# How to generate n-grams in scala?

Tags: scala, n-gram

I am trying to code dissociated press algorithm based on n-gram in scala. 
How to generate an n-gram for a large files:
For example, for the file containing "the bee is the bee of the bees".

1. First it has to pick a random n-gram. For example, the bee.
2. Then it has to look for n-grams starting with (n-1) words. For example, bee of.
3. it prints the last word of this n-gram. Then repeats.

Can you please give me some hints how to do it?
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I don't know what a n-gram is. Are you just choosing words randomly? Or has some logic?

Comment: @santiagobasulto Wikipedia is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

Comment: Is this by any chance related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256830/how-to-make-string-sequence-in-scala?

Answer (score 14):

Your questions could be a little more specific but here is my try.

```
val words = "the bee is the bee of the bees"
words.split(' ').sliding(2).foreach( p => println(p.mkString))
```

Comment: Not that this will only give you 2-grams. If n-grams are desired, then n needs to be parameterized.

Comment: @tuxdna but it can be easily adjusted

Answer (score 5):

You may try this with a parameter of n

```
val words = "the bee is the bee of the bees"
val w = words.split(" ")

val n = 4
val ngrams = (for( i <- 1 to n) yield w.sliding(i).map(p => p.toList)).flatMap(x => x)
ngrams foreach println

List(the)
List(bee)
List(is)
List(the)
List(bee)
List(of)
List(the)
List(bees)
List(the, bee)
List(bee, is)
List(is, the)
List(the, bee)
List(bee, of)
List(of, the)
List(the, bees)
List(the, bee, is)
List(bee, is, the)
List(is, the, bee)
List(the, bee, of)
List(bee, of, the)
List(of, the, bees)
List(the, bee, is, the)
List(bee, is, the, bee)
List(is, the, bee, of)
List(the, bee, of, the)
List(bee, of, the, bees)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a stream based approach. This will not required too much memory while computing n-grams.

```
object ngramstream extends App {

  def process(st: Stream[Array[String]])(f: Array[String] => Unit): Stream[Array[String]] = st match {
    case x #:: xs => {
      f(x)
      process(xs)(f)
    }
    case _ => Stream[Array[String]]()
  }

  def ngrams(n: Int, words: Array[String]) = {
    // exclude 1-grams
    (2 to n).map { i => words.sliding(i).toStream }
      .foldLeft(Stream[Array[String]]()) {
        (a, b) => a #::: b
      }
  }

  val words = "the bee is the bee of the bees"
  val n = 4
  val ngrams2 = ngrams(n, words.split(" "))

  process(ngrams2) { x =>
    println(x.toList)
  }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
List(the, bee)
List(bee, is)
List(is, the)
List(the, bee)
List(bee, of)
List(of, the)
List(the, bees)
List(the, bee, is)
List(bee, is, the)
List(is, the, bee)
List(the, bee, of)
List(bee, of, the)
List(of, the, bees)
List(the, bee, is, the)
List(bee, is, the, bee)
List(is, the, bee, of)
List(the, bee, of, the)
List(bee, of, the, bees)
```

Comment: I like it, not sure of the usefulness of `process`. Why not just do `ngrams(...).foreach(x=>println(x.toList))`?

Comment: @Mortimer: Interesting question. `process` is just an additional function. We can definitely use `ngrams2 foreach { x => println(x.toList)}`. Thanks :-)