# n grams scala output set transformation

Tags: scala, set, n-gram

```
def ngrams(n: Int, words: Array[String]) = {
// exclude 1-grams
(1 to n).map { i => words.sliding(i).toStream }
  .foldLeft(Stream[Array[String]]()) {
    (a, b) => a #::: b
  } }   
scala> val op2 =  ngrams(3, "how are you".split(" ")).foreach { x => println((x.mkString(" ")))}  
Output as :    
how
are
you
how are
are you
how are you
op2: Unit = ()
```

How to avoid the above ***Unit*** value , actually i wants to convert them to Set, because of the Unit=(), it's failing . So can you please help in output should be ***Set(how,are,you,how are,are you,how are you)*** 
Thanks for the post -- [How to generate n-grams in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258963/how-to-generate-n-grams-in-scala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the type signature for `op2`. You could do

1. remove the assignment to Op2

`ngrams(3, "how are you".split(" ")).foreach { x => println((x.mkString(" ")))}`

2. Change `.foreach` to `.map` and the call `op2` for the result.

`scala> val op2 =  ngrams(3, "how are you".split(" ")).map { x => x.mkString(" ")}.toList`

`scala> op2`

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the return type of `foreach` is `Unit`. So when you assign the output of `foreach` to `op2`, the type of `op2` is `Unit` and its value is `()`.

It sounds like what you want to do is the following:

1. calculate the n-grams using the `ngrams` method,
2. store the `Set` of n-grams to `op2`, and
3. print out all the n-grams.

Let's start with the type of the `ngrams` method:

```
(n: Int, words: Array[String]) => Stream[Array[String]]
```

It returns a `Stream`, which looks like it can easily be turned into a `Set` with `toSet`:

`ngrams(3, "how are you".split(" ")).toSet`

However, this is dangerous because in scala, `Array` equality is done by reference. It is much safer to turn your `Stream[Array[String]]` into a `Stream[List[String]]` so that any duplicates are removed (this is assuming that order matters in each ngram):

`val op2 = ngrams(3, "how are you".split(" ")).map(_.toList).toSet`

Now, it's easy to print out the `Set[List[String]]` the same way you did the `Stream[Array[String]]`:

`op2.foreach { x => println((x.mkString(" ")))}`

Because the result is `()`, the `Unit` type, there is no reason to assign it to a variable.

Comment: @MapReddy – note that Dan answered the question, not me.  I just edited it a bit, so you really have him to thank!  Thank him with an upvote :)